# Pandas python merge multiple file text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append

I have 2 file text:
file1.txt

```
abc
fdg
erg
```

file2.txt

```
pot
ezr
fds
```

i have make a csv file with 2 columns

```
columns = ['first','second']
my_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
```

i dont find how i can add file txt on column

i want

```
   first   second
0   abc     pot
1   fdg     ezr
2   erg     fds
```

i have try with loc or append but my result is bad.
i dont know how i can place item in file text in the good place on my df.
can you help me ?

Answer (score 4):

A good scalable solution would be to read the files in from a list of filepaths, then concat them together along axis 1.
Then you can use the `.to_csv` method to output the file that you require.

```
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
frames = []

for file in files:
    frames.append(pd.read_csv(file))

df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
df.to_csv('output.txt', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `names` if no csv header, default separator is `,`, if necessary change it:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep=',', names=['first'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep=',', names=['second'])
```

And then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```